# Running perl-script kpcli via cron failed

Tags: perl, ubuntu, cron

I'd like to run a script using kpcli (http://kpcli.sourceforge.net/) via cronjob. All works fine when running it interactively.

When running it the following minimum example via cronjob I get the following error-message.

```
46 22 * * *     myuser /usr/local/bin/kpcli --command "vers"
```

Here the error message

```
No usable Term::ReadLine::* modules found.
This list was tried:
 * Term::ReadLine::Gnu
 * Term::ReadLine::Perl
 * Term::ReadLine::Perl5
For more information, read the documentation: perldoc kpcli
```

Here is the output when running it via command line

```
kpcli: 3.4
Perl: v5.26.1
Operating system: linux ("Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS")
ReadLine being used: Term::ReadLine::Gnu

Pivotal Perl Modules for kpcli
 * File::KeePass: 2.03
 * Term::ShellUI: 0.92
 * Term::ReadKey: 2.37
 * Term::ReadLine: 1.16
 * Capture::Tiny: 0.48
 * Clipboard: 0.13
 * Math::Random::ISAAC: 1.003
 * Term::ReadLine::Gnu: 1.35
 * Authen::OATH: not installed (optional)
 * Sub::Install: not installed (optional)
```

I also tried to set the variable

```
PERL5LIB=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26
```

But nothing changed :(

What's wrong?

Comment: Where did you set the variable? You can set it in the crontab itself.

Comment: From the shell where it works, please provide the output of `set | grep -P '^PERL'; which perl; perl -e'use Term::ReadLine; CORE::say $INC{"Term/ReadLine/Gnu.pm"};'; head -n 1 /usr/local/bin/kpcli`

Comment: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26` seems like a really weird path to (need to) tell Perl about. This doesn't seem right.

Comment: Here is the output `/usr/bin/perl
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26/Term/ReadLine/Gnu.pm
#!/usr/bin/perl`.  I add also some information at answer one yesterday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have it :). I have unset all environment variables step by step by shell script. The result was that the variable TERM="xterm" was set in my env but not in the cron env. After setting it in cron all works fine

Comment: It is apparently enough to just have TERM set to anything. for Example TERM=WTF also works. Why do some libraries have so weird and unintuitive restrictions?!

Answer (score 2):

The [PERL5LIB](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#ENVIRONMENT) is a user's environment variable; the system's utility `cron` knows nothing about it.

Further, what you invoke from `crontab` mostly runs "out of" your home directory; this can depend on the system but it is generally *not* from where the script is.  So then *that* place is the script's working directory.

Clearly the module `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` is installed in a non-standard location and when the script runs via cron it altogether cannot find that module (and perhaps yet others).

There are various ways about this

- Set `PERL5LIB` right on the command line in the crontab

  ```
    SHELL=/bin/bash
    MAILTO=your@email.address

    * * * * * PERL5LIB=/path/as/needed  /full/path/script.pl arguments
  ```

  The environment variables I set in the beginning are often already set to reasonable values (but they may not be). Consider what other environment may be needed, if any.  See your system's documentation  for `crontab(5)` and test
- Change to a directory from which the script is known to work

  ```
    * * * * * (cd /path/to/where/it/works; ./script.pl arguments)
  ```
- Make the script itself change to the desired working directory by adding to it

  ```
    use FindBin qw($RealBin);
    BEGIN { 
        chdir $RealBin or die "Can't chdir to $RealBin: $!";
    };
  ```

  This must be done *before* any `use` statements that need the script to already be in the particular directory; perhaps all those that refer to non-standard locations.

The solution where the order of compile-time statements matters can be fragile here. On the other hand, in that way the working directory is set up right in the script and sometimes that is precisely what is needed.

There is certainly a rationale for doing both, change the working directory and set `PERL5LIB`

```
* * * * * (cd /full/path; PERL5LIB=path1:path2:...  ./script.pl arguments)
```

Comment: Hey, that's what I already tried. I changed in the crontab the entry to

    export PERL5LIB=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.2; /usr/local/bin/kpcli --command "vers"

but I got the same error. Is PERL5LIB the correct path for ubuntu? I took this because there is a subdirectory term/ReadLine/Gnu.

Comment: @steff123 I don't know what is the suitable `PERL5LIB` on your system.  (What does `perldoc -l Term::ReadLine` output?)   More to the point, how does it go with the second option (bullet)?  That should work -- change where you `cd` as appropriate -- if running manually out of that directory does.

Comment: @steff123, `PERL5LIB` is used if you installed Perl modules into a non-standard location. It's used to point to any and all such locations that you used. We can't tell you what you used, but both `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.2` seem highly suspect.

Comment: I am feeling like a DAU. The `cd` approach in cron doesn't work too. `perldoc -l Term::ReadLine` returns `/usr/share/perl/5.26/Term/ReadLine.pm`. Using `/usr/share/perl/5.26` as `PERL5LIB` changed nothing. I installed perl via the ubuntu package manager apt and readline was installed as dependency of kpcli with the package libterm-readline-gnu-perl. Any Ideas?

Comment: @steff123  So you have multiple installations of `Term::ReadLine`, judged by your comments here and under the question.  The `/usr/lib...` version shouldn't need `PERL5LIB` so I suspect that the program you want to use needs _this_ version, from `/usr/share...`.  Do you normally have `PERL5LIB` set, and what is it?  Perhaps try to combine the first two options, first `cd` to a directory from which it works _and_ then set `PERL5LIB` and run it `(cd ...; PERL5LIB=/....   program arguments)`

Comment: @steff123 "_The cd approach in cron doesn't work too_"  --- how? What happens?